# NotificationCenter.default.addObserver not accessing the method

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create make my view move after the keyboard open. But I am stuck on a very unexpected problem.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    print("a")
}
```

However, my `keyboardWillShow` function seems to never have been accessed since the "a" was never printed. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: check my answer for your problem you will get idea about NotificationCenter

Answer (score 0):

**Add NSNotificationCenter**

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboradWillChangeFrame(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)


 @objc private func keyboradWillChangeFrame(notification : NSNotification) {
        // Here your code 
}
```

**call that NSNotificationCenter method.**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```